# How would you simulate space RTS in infinite universe

Tags: artificial-intelligence, space, generated

I have a game design/programming question.
Let`s say I create procedurally generated galaxy (2D), but you play it as RTS. So you can pan camera everywhere (At least where you have explored and have units/structures).

Now, the design question comes. There will be other AI opponents or factions. Now where you as player discover tens or hundreds of planets and discover other factions, you just cannot keep them in memory and process their moves, or the game will simply crash.

How would you simulate their progress? Their ship building, expansion, war between them etc.

In game like Sins of Solar empire, galaxy has few dozen planets, so they can process all AI even if you don't see them.
But when you have 10 000 planets, I don't want to just hide enemy AI and when you come there few hours later, since the AI would be on the same level as you left it hours ago.

Comment: might seem a stupid question, but does it make any sense to keep so many planets? there will no way to explore them all anyway.. I would think os fomething like: when i reach a new planet this planet starts to exist, with the development not at zero but at some point compatible with the playing time. And from then on i keep it in memory. If you reach a planet later it will be more advanced, if you reach it sooner it will be more primitive.

Comment: or when you reach a planet it calculates everything that happened in between. instead of keeping it real time it could do sort of a fast forward for that specific planet when you get near it. and when you are far it keeps it in pause.

Comment: Well the thing is, I want to do something special. There is sins of solar empire with limited number of planets/systems. And its 3D, thats where I cannot compete :) On the other hand, game like Dwarf Fortress, with simple 2D graphics is very popular. Also its not only about planet, its how AI builds ships and structures around it, how it mines asteroids in system etc. Thats where the simulation problem comes.

Comment: StackOverflow is just for programming questions, not idea/design ones, though.

Comment: Well as I can see, this is more of general question, even for programming and memory management. Not only design.

Comment: There is a difference between *big* and *infinite*.

Comment: @dlask in programming terminology, nothing is infinite (well not even in physical world anyway). By infinite I mean player can go to one direction and world will generate until they hit like 32 or 64-bit integer cap.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about game design. This would be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com, but is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some of [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)) algorithms.

As an example, you can define a set of key metrics for each opponent or fraction (location, number of planets, buildings, ships, fleet strength and so on).

Then you can simulate key scenarios of changing of these metrics for the most common situations as one opponent grows separately, one opponent joins to some of formations, one formation fights against other formation and so on. And use it to build the graph of key possible scenarios and then use them to calculate next metrics for each of the opponents.

In a case of new scenario, which not in the list of common scenarios you can simulate it and add to database of scenarios, when you will collect enough tries then you can reduce it too. It is also the way to do reduction initially. Therefore, if you did enough tries initially, you can get many ready reduced scenarios with high probability of using it instead of modeling of all events.

After that, you can randomly or by using such approaches as [Genetic Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) instantiate exact opponents with exact planets, units, buildings, resources and so on in given location.

In addition, you can store planets, key buildings and units of opponent from the past visit into the DB and use it as a base instead of new random planets/units/buildings generation. So even after return player can find some familiar object, if the situation did not change dramatically.